# how to find host System information of LAN network using host IP address?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am just want to know is there any command in window cmd to find a host system information using its IP-address from another host inside the LAN network.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [MSINFO32.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/msinfo32.html) with the `/computer` switch: get details from a remote computer...

Answer (score 0):

```
     systeminfo /s 127.0.0.1
```

or thousands of properties `wmic`.

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 computersystem get /format:List

wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process get /format:List

wmic /node:127.0.0.1 bios get /format:List
```

See

```
systeminfo /s

wmic /?

wmic process /?

wmic process /get /?
```

Plus many inbuilt commands do network machines like `schtasks /?`. Even `Dir \\127.0.0.1\c$`.

### .